# Problem while using MessageContract attribute : Exception -> End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wse

I am moving my WSE3 web services to the WCF. But the client is WSE3 client.

All the Operation Contracts return an instance of the `MessageContract` classes. This works for 2 operations but somehow fails for one operation of the same service contract. The error is:

`The signature or decryption was invalid.`

When I look into WCF trace file, I found the following:

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'MyOperationName'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'MyOperationName' from namespace 'urn:MyProject:MyModule:2006:04:MyAuthorizationModule'.
```

**My observation is, when I use `XmlRoot` attribute to decorate response class (instead of using `MessageContract` attribute), I do not get this exception. However, response object cannot be deserialized. i.e. I can see the XML response in input trace but since the expected XML structure does not match, service call returns `null` at client side.**

The `MessageContract` class has only one public property (`MessageBodyMember`) which returns an instance of another class which is decorated with the `XmlRoot` attribute.  This  class (which is decorated with `xmlRoot`) has a property which gives the `Collection` of objects of some entity class which has `XmlElement` properties in it.

Which all things I need to check/verify? 
I can provide class code snippets if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with the MessageContract which was used in response. The problem was with the input parameter to the OperationContract.

When I looked at the old WSE3 web service proxy method (`WebMethod`) and created the `OperationContract` for it in WCF service, the `OparationContract` I created did not accept any parameter.

While investigating this issue, I used the `svcutil.exe` to create .NET classes from the WSDL of the old WSE3 service. When I looked into the specific `OperationContract` I came to know that I need to create a `MessageContract` which will be used as request parameter to the `OperationContract`. So I created a `MessageContract` without any `MessageBodyMember`. When I used it, the problem got resolved.

Obviously, if we compare the `OperationContract` signature with the ASMX `WebMethod` signature, they dont match since we have introduced input parameter. But this works. I do not know how and why. **It would be great if someone explains why it works.**