# How to use MessageContract correctly in the WCF OperationContracts?

Tags: wcf

Can someone point (or answer here, if possible) me to the material/reference which describes how to use `MessageContrac`t in WCF operations correctly. I have read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) document.

I would like to know:
1) What limitations are there while using `MessageContract` as return value of the operation contract?
2) What if the class decorated withe the `MessageContract` has a property which returns an object of the class which is decorated with `XmlRoot`? 
3) Are there any limitations or considerations if `MessageContract` is going to contain arrays or collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The limitation is that once you use `MessageContract` for request description you have to use it for response as well and vice-versa. The only exception are operations returning void or accepting no parameters.
2. WCF uses `DataContractSerializer` by default but you can switch it to `XmlSerializer` by marking contract, service or operation with `XmlSerailazerFormat` attribute. In such case serialization will ignore `DataContract` / `DataMember` attributes and start to use common Xml serialization attributes (including `XmlRoot`). What is most important is that `MessageContract` is not related to used serializer - it can be used with both `DataContract` and Xml serialization.
3. I would pass the collection nested in other element. I'm not sure how if it is possible to pass unwrapped collection directly into soap:Body because it should be represented as multiple body elements which are handled separately by `MessageContract` - each is marked with `MessageBodyMember` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for 'to the point' answer. +1.I've a `MessageContract` which has `MessageBodyMemeber` of the type which is decorated with `XmlRoot` attribute.  That `XmlRoot` class has property which gives `Collection` of another type which has `XmlElement`s. In this case, when I use `XmlSerializerFormat`, I get errors while browsing service. What is wrong in this scenario? When I don't use it, I can browse the service but at run time, in code, I get the exception  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263310/problem-while-using-messagecontract-attribute-exception-end-element-body-f . Pls help

Answer (score 1):

The MessageContract attribute enables/requires you to specify the format of the entire message for the operation, with finely grained control over how the message is serialized / deserialized, as opposed to the DataContract/DataMember attributes which control whether individual fields are included in the serialization.

The XmlRoot attribute is used by the System.Xml.XmlSerializer class when processing serializable classes; WCF uses the DataContractSerializer which does not use this attribute.

More info in this question: [Why does the XmlRoot attribute gets ignored in WCF and how to overcome this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013689/why-does-the-xmlroot-attribute-gets-ignored-in-wcf-and-how-to-overcome-this)

Comment: Thanks for referring to the SO question. It was helpful. In my application when I use `MessageContract` which has property returning object of the `XmlRoot` class I get exception. Exception is: ** The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'MyOperation'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. **. Have you seen such exception in scenarios of the MessageContract ?